# Stored Procedure Activity procedure parameter with int data type in Azure Data Factory

Tags: stored-procedures, azure-data-factory

I am working on a stored procedure activity to load data into one of my table. The procedure expects an int parameter to be passed and the value for this comes from the lookup output firstrow field. But when I pass the lookup output value for the parameter the pipeline is not getting executed. I have tried to convert the values as well and even used a variable to store. Any option to process the same?

Regards,
Sandeep

Answer (score 0):

Can you send the detailed error when you try to execute the pipeline?

Thanks,

Pratik

Comment: Pratik, It was an error from my end, the substring returned contained a extra character. I have removed it and worked without any issue. Thank you for your time.

Comment: That's great to know Sandeep. Good luck.